# Convert SQLite CSV output to JSON

Tags: csv, json, conversion, sqlite

I want to format SQLite output in JSON format from the command line. Currently, I have CSV output that looks like this:

```
label1,value1
label2,value2
label3,value3
...
```

Now I'd like to have it formatted like this:

```
{'label1' : 'value1',  'label2': 'value2', ... }
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32002086/4957508 might be helpful

Comment: see also: http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this with GNU `awk` and `sed`... not sure if it will with other versions.

```
awk -F, '{printf "'\''%s'\'' : '\''%s'\'', ", $1, $2} END {print "}" }' input.csv | sed -e 's/^/{/' -e 's/, }/}/' > output.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Valid JSON uses double quotes so:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{print "{"} {if (notfirst) {print ","}; print "\"" $1 "\":\"" $2 "\""; notfirst=1} END {print "\"\":\"\"}" }' input.csv
```

Also simpler not using sed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have this:

```
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable;
┌────────┬────────┐
│ field1 │ field2 │
├────────┼────────┤
│ label1 │ value1 │
│ label2 │ value2 │
│ label3 │ value3 │
└────────┴────────┘
```

... we can extract the data as JSON with the `field1` field renamed `key` and the `field2` field renamed `value`:

```bash
$ sqlite3 mydatabase.db '.mode json' 'SELECT field1 AS key, field2 AS value FROM mytable'
[{"key":"label1","value":"value1"},
{"key":"label2","value":"value2"},
{"key":"label3","value":"value3"}]
```

This can by passed directly through `jq`'s `from_entries` filter to create the output you require:

```bash
$ sqlite3 mydatabase.db '.mode json' 'SELECT field1 AS key, field2 AS value FROM mytable' | jq from_entries
{
  "label1": "value1",
  "label2": "value2",
  "label3": "value3"
}
```

Note that [the `from_entries` filter in `jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries-from_entries-with_entries) expects an array of "entries", i.e., objects with `key` and `value` keys.

Allowing SQLite to output JSON and then handling that JSON with `jq` ensures that data containing quotes, newlines, and other potentially problematic characters are handled correctly:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable;
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┐
│       field1        │   field2   │
├─────────────────────┼────────────┤
│ label1              │ value1     │
├─────────────────────┼────────────┤
│ label2              │ value2     │
├─────────────────────┼────────────┤
│ label3              │ value3     │
├─────────────────────┼────────────┤
│ label "with quotes" │ value with │
│                     │ newline    │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

```bash
$ sqlite3 mydatabase.db '.mode json' 'SELECT field1 AS key, field2 AS value FROM mytable' | jq from_entries
{
  "label1": "value1",
  "label2": "value2",
  "label3": "value3",
  "label \"with quotes\"": "value with\nnewline"
}
```

---

If you have a pre-existing CSV file created by a SELECT query while `.mode csv` is active in SQLite, you can still use the same trick with renaming the fields `key` and `value` and passing them through `from_entries` in `jq` by first using Miller to relabel the fields and converting from CSV to JSON:

```bash
$ mlr --c2j label key,value mydata.csv | jq from_entries
{
  "label2": "value2",
  "label3": "value3",
  "label \"with quotes\"": "value with\nnewline"
}
```

If you have deleted the header line, given `mlr` the `-N` option to signify header-less CSV input.

Obviously, if you're already using Miller, you can get it to do all the work without involving `jq`:

```bash
$ mlr --c2j label key,value then put -q 'end { emit @record } @record[$key] = $value' then cut -x -f key,value mydata.csv
[
{
  "label2": "value2",
  "label3": "value3",
  "label \"with quotes\"": "value with\nnewline"
}
]
```

This reads the data from `mydata.csv`, relabels the two fields and then collects all the data in a new record whose fields depend on the `key` field's value in each input record.  The two initial `key` and `value` fields are then deleted, and the output is created as an array with a single JSON object.